# How to understand the '...' operator used with Boolean comparisons

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
select = []
0.upto 5 do |value|
  select << value if (value==2)...(value==2)
end
p select # [2,3,4,5]
```

Can anyone tell me how to understand this code?

Comment: It is a documented control structure named ["flip-flop"](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Flip-Flop).

Answer (score 5):

I learned something researching this because I've never seen the range operator used on boolean values. Apparently in this context its called a "flip flop" operator. Basically, the condition evaluates `False` until the first part of the conditional is `True`. Then it "flips" and evaluates `True` until the 2nd part evaluates `True`. In your example, the 2nd part will never evaluate to `True` as its already passed the valid condition of `value == 2` therefore it will continue on with the range provided. You can see this flip-flopping in action if you change the 2nd condition to `value == 4`:

```
select = []
0.upto 5 do |value|
  select << value if (value==2)...(value==4)
end
p select # [2,3,4]
```

Reference: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/

Comment: The example you give is ... operator, how about .. operator?
`select = []
0.upto 5 do |value|
  select << value if (value==2)..(value==2)
end
p select #[2]
`

Comment: In this context, `..` and `...` are the same.